# Using awk to remove leading zeros gives octal results

Tags: bash, shell, awk

### Background

I have a simple problem that has consumed the better part of a day for me.  In short, I am trying to remove leading zeroes from a string using `awk`.  **Before everyone flags this as a duplicate, however, the question is NOT about how to remove leading zeroes** (that is simply the end I am trying to achieve).  Additoinally, this is specifically about variables as they are read; I am well aware of format strings for output operations.

### The Problem

My problem is thus: whenever I try to typecast a given variable to an integer, `awk` is reading the leading zeroes and treating the input number as an octal string.  I have some simple examples to demonstrate the behavior below:

```
$ echo "0012" | awk '{$1=$1+0}1'
10
$ echo "0012" | awk '{$1=+$1}1'
10
$ echo "0011" | awk '{print ($1 + 0)}'
9
$ echo "0000" | awk '{$1=$1+0}1'
0
```

Now, I have seen a number of solutions offering a variety of `sed` commands to 'pre-process' and remove the leading zeroes.  Unfortunately, a completely valid input for me is `0000`, which string-based solutions collapse to an empty string.

### The Question

In short, how to I force `awk` to treat a variable it reads as decimal, regardless of leading zeroes?

### References

[How to delete all characters but the last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128812/how-to-delete-all-characters-but-the-last)

[strip leading zeros in awk program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515911/strip-leading-zeros-in-awk-program)

[Removing Leading Zeros within awk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111713/removing-leading-zeros-within-awk-file)

### Update

Things I forgot to mention in the original post: I am trying to coalesce `0000` into a single `0`.  Additionally, my ideal solution is `awk`-only due to the slim nature of my environment (is halfway between embedded Linux and a desktop OS).  The `awk` in question is provided by BusyBox 1.18.1 but everything else should be extremely close to a modern desktop version of Linux.

Comment: Well, it'd be nice to inform which version of `awk` you are using, because the tests I ran with `GNU Awk 4.1.0` always give the expected result. For your tests, in order, I've got `12, 12, 11, and 0`.

Comment: I got the same results as @Rubens with `mawk` and the debian distribution of `original-awk`. However, you can convince GNU `awk` to produce the  results in the OP if you provide it with the command-line-flag `--non-decimal-data`. Is it possible that you have an `awk` alias which sets that flag? (Type `alias awk` to find out).

Comment: What does `awk 'BEGIN{print OFMT,CONVFMT}'` show for you?  I can't make any strangeness happen with gawk 3.1.5 by setting those, but one of those might be implicated in printing out numerics if they aren't `%.6g %.6g`.  According to the gawk manual it's because the string is considered an integer which is a special case, so those formats aren't used.  As for non-gawk...?

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness around the environment; I had assumed this would be a 'standard' fix.  Anyways, I am using the `awk` that is packaged with BusyBox 1.18.1 (this is not for an Android phone, though still an embedded-like environment).  I am not seeing any aliases for `awk` reported.  As for the format specifiers, printing both `OFMT` and `CONVFMT` gives me:  `%.6g %.6g`.  So, near as I can tell and outside of using a BusyBox version of `awk` , nothing appears to be out of place.

Comment: @phobos51594. Pretty well all busybox versions of standard utilities have enough idiosyncracies (or, if you prefer, bugs) that it is essentially obligatory to mention the fact that you are using it whenever asking questions about unexpected behaviour. Just saying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With what `busybox` calls `awk`, it seems to be possible to do the following:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 0000 0011 0012 |
  busybox awk '{print ($1".")+0}'
0
11
12
```

Posix requires that `awk` use the equivalent of `strtod` to convert data values to numbers, and all the `awk` implementations I could find do just that, except for `busybox awk`. (`Busybox` does not claim to be Posix compatible, of course, but it is sometimes aggressively incompatible, as in this case.) So `{print $1 + 0}` should work just fine, but it doesn't in the case of `busybox awk`, which will allow hexadecimal or octal integers in input data.

Appending a `.` to the number forces an integer to be treated as a floating point number, and has no effect on real floating point numbers, since `strtod` just stops when it encounters a character which can't be decoded as part of a number. Of course, it will also have no effect if the field is not entirely numeric, so if you expect fields like `0017a` which you want to convert to `17a` (or even `17`), this solution is not for you.

As a side note, the precedence of string concatenation in `awk` is lower than the precedence of addition (and higher than comparison operators), so the parentheses are actually necessary; `awk` would parse `print $1""+0` as `print $1(""+0)`, which would append a 0 to the string value of `$1`. The GNU `awk` manual suggests that you should always parenthesize concatenation except in trivial expressions, and that strikes me as good advice.

Also, as I was trying to reverse engineer `busybox awk`'s numeric conversion algorithm, I discovered that it treats `012e3` as the integer 10, rather than 12000. Both `12e3` and `012.e3` are converted to 12000, though. `busybox` is nothing if not idiosyncratic.

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm.  If I may be so bold: why?  Apparently my `awk-fu` has a long way to go.

Comment: Ah, makes sense.  So it is a float without any fractional part which then just gets spat back out as a traditional integer?  If that is the case, will this solution be portable across `awk` versions or is this a BusyBox-only solution?

Comment: @phobos51594: Moved explanatory comments to answer for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{printf "%o\n", $1 + 0}' <<< 0012
12
```

Comment: That won't work if the number is `0019`. (And, by the way, what's wrong with `%s\\n`?)

Answer (score 0):

builing upon answers from above, one can simplify

> `($1".")+0`

… by pruning away the `"0"` ...

> `+($1 ".")`

> ```
> gawk -n '( $++NF = +($!_ ".") )^_'
> ```

```
0021 21
0020 20
0019 19
0018 18

0012 12
0011 11
0010 10
0000 0

012 12
011 11
010 10
000 0
```